# httplistener doesn't work on port 80?

Tags: .net, iis-7, httplistener

The setting: Windows 7, IIS installed and running.

The following piece of code:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://server.com:8080/path");
listener.Start();
```

Works like charm - any request made against the server is received in my code.

However, when I make the following change (moving to port 80) http.sys/IIS (not sure which) returns HTTP 503 errors:

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://server.com:80/path");
```

I've tried setting URLACLs, running this process as admin, etc., but nothing changes this behavior.

Edit: to clear this out - there is not actual networking involved in this mess. All this is done locally on a single machine, for testing purposes (both server and client).

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't IIS listen on this port ?

Comment: @Mitch, If the firewall would have been an issue, I wouldn't have received a 503.

@Dani, IIS listens on this port as well, http.sys allows multiple processes to share URLs between them. That's the whole point.

Comment: The problem here is that all Windows desktop operating systems have limited incoming connections (10 simulaneous connections). If you can ignore this limitation, the steps would be: •on your router: forward port 80 TCP to your PC's local IP address •allow port 80 on your Windows firewall for incoming connections •from outside, use the IP address your provider assigned to your internet connection or use a service like dyndns.com.

Comment: what's name does iis use / and what name do your listener use ?

Comment: @jjj, all is local to my machine. no actual network is involved here, only loopback.

Comment: @Dani - my name. but does it matter? I also tried "http://+:80/" vs. "http://+:8080", same thing happens.

Comment: Try `netstat -a -b -o` command. And you'll see which process owns 80 port.

Comment: @Vasiliy - it's "System" for both ports.

Comment: Forward port 80 requests on your public IP to the computer via your router. If your public IP is dynamic, not static, you may want to use a service such as no-ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, not sure why, and I hate such answers, however... **the problem went away**. I can verify that no code was changed, and it wasn't the transient state of the machine in question as I tried rebooting it more than once during the problem trials.

I have no idea what caused it.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  After changing ports I was using, the problem went away.

Comment: I have had the same issue with the HttpListener, I have to reboot my dev environment from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. I developped my listener initially on port 8080 which most samples use, then switch to port 80. The first time I ran on port 80, I got either the IIS start page (IIS role is not installed on my server currently, may be an IE cache issue) or a blank page. I had breakpoints in the handler and could see the requests coming through and being answered to successfully. After re-compiling (clean), re-installing my service and restarting IE, the issue was gone. No code change.

So if you hit that issue, try recompile clean, re-install your service (or app) and restart IE.